# Convert row to columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a input like this block of line are delimited by empty line, need to convert row to columns

Input

```
HEAD1
IF
FI
GH

HEAD2
PU
GT

HEAD3
FG
DF
YT
GU
```

Need to print  like this:

```
HEAD1 IF FI GH
HEAD2 PU GT
HEAD3 FG DF YT GU
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
HEAD1 IF FI GH
HEAD2 PU GT
HEAD3 FG DF YT GU
```

When `RS`, the input record separator, is blank rather than the default, a newline character, `awk` will divide the input into records based on the occurrence of two or more consecutive newlines in the input, i.e. one or more blank lines will taken as marking the end of a record.  This is usually referred to as putting using `awk` in "paragraph mode".

The code then sets the first field to itself.  This seems like an no-op operation, but it provokes `awk` to re-form the current record for output.  The default values for `ORS` (output record separator) and `OFS` (output field separator) are used (a newline character and a space character respectively), so when the record then is printed, all the fields are printed on a single line with spaces in-between them, terminated at the end with a newline character.

You may get the fields separated by other strings or characters by modifying the value of `OFS`:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v OFS='\t' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
HEAD1   IF      FI      GH
HEAD2   PU      GT
HEAD3   FG      DF      YT      GU
```

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v OFS=',' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
HEAD1,IF,FI,GH
HEAD2,PU,GT
HEAD3,FG,DF,YT,GU
```

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v OFS='::' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
HEAD1::IF::FI::GH
HEAD2::PU::GT
HEAD3::FG::DF::YT::GU
```

The `awk` code could be shortened into `{ $1 = $1 }; 1`, where the trailing `1` would cause the current record to be printed by invoking the default action unconditionally.  This is a fairly common way to do unconditional printing of the current record.

---

Using `sed` instead:

```
$ sed -e '/./ { H; $!d; }' -e 'x; y/\n/ /; s/.//' file
HEAD1 IF FI GH
HEAD2 PU GT
HEAD3 FG DF YT GU
```

This appends the current line to the hold space with `H` if the line contains anything.  The line is appended to the hold space with a delimiting newline character.  If this was not the last line of input, the pattern spaces is discarded with `d` and we continue immediately from the start with the next line of input.

If the current line is empty, we swap in the hold space with `x` (which, since the pattern space is empty, also has the effect of clearing the hold space), replace all newlines with spaces, and lop off the first character (which will be an extra  space character).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` in paragraph mode:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v OFS=' ' '{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}' file
HEAD1 IF FI GH
HEAD2 PU GT
HEAD3 FG DF YT GU
```

- `RS=` Setting `RS` this way, the input records are separated by blank lines.
- `FS='\n'` This way you can treat every line in each paragraph as a field of the record.
- with `for` we go through all the fields and with `printf` we print them under the conditional expression known as `ternary expression`: if exp1 `i<NF` returns true, `OFS` gets executed; otherwise, `ORS` gets executed.